# Finite lattices that are Koszul

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, lattice-theory

Let $L$ be a finite lattice and $A=KL$ the incidence algebra of $L$.
It should be true that $L$ is modular if and only if the algebra $KL$ is quadratic (since being modular is equivalent to having no pentagon sublattice and pentagons are non-quadratic). Note that being Koszul implies that an algebra is quadratic.

> Question 1: Which modular lattice $L$ have the property that $KL$ is a Koszul algebra? (Does it depend on the field?)

All distributive lattices should be Koszul.

> Question 2: Is there a nice ring-theoretic/combinatorial interpretation of the Koszul dual algebra of the incidence algebra of a modular lattice that is Koszul (other than using the quadratic perp)?

Comment: You need Cohen Macauley. I can find you the reference.  It was proved by two people simultaneously

Comment: Polo and Woodcock showed the incidence algebra of a graded poset is koszul iff each open interval in the poset is Cohen-Macauley over K

Comment: D. Woodcock. Cohen-Macaulay complexes and Koszul rings. J. London Math. Soc. (2), 57(2):398–410, 1998 and P. Polo. On Cohen-Macaulay posets, Koszul algebras and certain modules associated to Schubert varieties. Bull. London Math. Soc., 27(5):425–434, 1995.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Thanks, I wonder whether this leads to an elementary order theoretic characterisation when modular lattices are Koszul.

Comment: I don't think so.  It's equivalent to Cohen-Macaulay which doesn't have a simple characterization but there are known sufficient conditions

Comment: Lexicographic shellability implies Cohen Macaulay and I think semimodular lattices are but I forget

Comment: Every interval of a modular (even semimodular) lattice is Cohen-Macaulay, so by the discussion above all modular lattices are Koszul.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, which completely answer question 1. Maybe you can turn the comments to an answer for this thread if you like. The result is quite nice and I wonder why it is not stated anywhere : A lattice L is Koszul if and only if it is modular.

Comment: @Mare, being modular is not necessary.  Semimodular is enough. And I’m not sure that is necessary

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Oh, then my guess is wrong that quadratic is the same as modular. I thought having a pentagon as a sublattice forces the relation to be non-quadratic but that seems to be wrong then. Ill think about it again.

Comment: I don't think a nice description beyond the quadratic perp is known. For example, the koszul dual of the intersection lattice of a hyperplane arrangement is the algebra of the hyperplane face monoid but there is no obvious or easy proof of this.

Comment: Look at the semimodular but nonmodular in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semimodular_lattice. The Pentagon is embedded as a sublattice but the Pentagon does not embed in the hasse diagram, which is the relevant issue for a Quiver presentation. There are some elements in the lattice between various elements of the Pentagon

Comment: You might look at our paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.05446.pdf#page107. We look at strongly connected graded posets. These have quadratic incidence algebras.  This property abstracts a property of face posets of regular CW decompositions of a sphere.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a summary of what I know, with @RichardStanley's remark taken into account.  It was shown independently by Polo and by Woodcock that the incidence algebra of a graded poset is Koszul iff each open interval of the poset is Cohen-Macaulay (over the field in question).  See P. Polo. On Cohen-Macaulay posets, Koszul algebras and certain modules associated to Schubert varieties. Bull. London Math. Soc., 27(5):425–434, 1995 and D. Woodcock. Cohen-Macaulay complexes and Koszul rings. J. London Math. Soc. (2), 57(2):398–410, 1998.

A semimodular lattice has Cohen-Macaulay open intervals (as pointed out by @RichardStanley)  and so has a Koszul incidence algebra.  This includes modular lattices.

Being modular is not necessary for being quadratic.  The issue is the Hasse diagram need not contain a pentagon for a non-modular lattice.  The pentagon is just a sublattice but it is not "convexly" embedded.

A fairly general class of graded posets with quadratic incidence algebras (and maybe they are exactly the class) are those which are what is sometimes called strongly connected, meaning that the order complex of each closed interval is a chamber complex (meaning any two facets are connected by a gallery as people study them in the theory of buildings).  This means that any two maximal chains with the same top and bottom can be connected by a sequence of moves where you change only one element of the chain at each step.  Semimodular lattices are strongly conencted, for example.  We prove in Lemma 7.4 of https://www.ams.org/books/memo/1345/memo1345.pdf (you can also find it on ArXiv) that the incidence algebra of a strongly connected poset is quadratic.  We also observe the quadratic dual is defined simply by reversing the Hasse diagram and taking the relation which is the sum of all paths of length 2.  This is the quadratic perp but it is a nicer description in this case.

We show that for geometric lattices associated to oriented matroids (including central hyperplane arrangements), the Koszul dual of the incidence algebra is the monoid algebra of the monoid of covectors of the oriented matroid.  But the proof involves a nontrivial topological argument to show that this monoid has a quiver presentation matching the quadratic perp.  We prove a similar thing for intersection semilattices of affine hyperplane arrangements and affine oriented matroids, as well as some other CW complexes that have a left regular band multiplication on its face poset including finite CAT(0) cube complexes.  Again the incidence algebra of a certain strongly connected meet semilattice is Koszul dual to the semigroup algebra of the left regular band of the CW complex.

I don't know of a general combinatorial description of the Koszul dual.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is the arxiv version identitcal in terms of content to the book version?

Comment: I think so. Pretty close if not exact

Comment: I'm fairly confident  for graded posets quadratic incidence algebra is equivalent to strongly connected.  I think if it is quadratic the admissible ideal must actually be generated by all differences of paths of length 2.  Then I think writing the difference of paths of length n as belonging to this ideal should produce a gallery.